# Can't register account using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

For training purposes trying to test registering using Selenium WebDriver. However, when I fill up all my registration information, I press join now, but the page just load about 1s and nothing happen. I checked and I found that my account have not been registered yet. How can I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui as pag
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


option =Options()
option.add_extension('D:\\c_file\\mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl.zip')
# option.add_argument("--incognito")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

driver.get("http://sephora.com")
time.sleep(2)
pag.hotkey('esc')
time.sleep(2)
pag.hotkey('esc')
time.sleep(2)



#Create account
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button').click()
time.sleep(1)

#Email
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/input')
email.send_keys('abctesting@testsep.com')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/button[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)

first_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/input')
first_name.send_keys('richard')
time.sleep(0.5)

last_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/input')
last_name.send_keys('ng')
time.sleep(0.5)

password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/input')
password.send_keys('Ads123123$')
time.sleep(5)

phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/div/div/div/input')
phone.send_keys('0943302726312')
time.sleep(0.5)

month = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[7]/div/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div/select')
month.send_keys('o')
time.sleep(0.5)

date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[7]/div/fieldset/div[2]/div[2]/div/select')
date.send_keys('12')
time.sleep(0.5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/button').click()
time.sleep(1)
```

This is the register form:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwdiM.png)